# Queue using Array (Using only the Array, the size and the start index) and liked list (Using only the size and the last Node)

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, queue

I’m looking to implement a Queue using an array and a linked list in java. The only thing is, I want to only use the size and the starting index while implementing it using the array, and only using the size and the last node while using a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I am just going to use Object for the type to be stored in the queues

Array Based

```
public class ArrayQueue {

    private int size;

    private Object[] objects;

    public ArrayQueue(){
        size = 0;
        objects = new Object[size];
    }

    //Add object to end of queue
    public void push(Object obj){
        size++;
        Object[] newArr = new Object[size];
        for(int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
            newArr[i] = objects[i];
        }
        newArr[newArr.length-1] = obj;
        objects = newArr;
    }

    //Release first object in queue
    public Object pop(){
        Object result = objects[0];
        size--;
        Object[] newArr = new Object[size];
        for(int i = 1; i < objects.length; i++){
            newArr[i] = objects[i];
        }
        objects = newArr;
        return result;
    }



}
```

Linked Based

```
public class LinkedQueue {

    private int size;

    private Node end;

    public LinkedQueue(){
        size = 0;
        end = null;
    }

    public void push(Object obj){
        size++;
        end = new Node(obj,end);
    }

    public Object pop(){
        Node lastNode = null; // This just makes it easier to remove the last node;
        Node currNode = end;
        while(currNode.prev != null){
            lastNode = currNode;
            currNode  = currNode.prev;
        }
        if(size > 1){lastNode.prev = null;}
        else{ end = null;}

        size--;
        return currNode.obj;
    }

}
```

Node Class

```
public class Node {

    public Node prev;

    public Object obj;

    public Node(Object obj,Node prev){
        this.obj = obj;
        this.prev = prev;
    }

}
```

If you have any questions on why I did what I did lmk!